# Error 1001: The specified service already exists

Tags: windows, service, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall/install an existing Windows service in Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2008.

In my MSI project properties, I have the following pertinent ones set and am still getting this error. I just want to be able to automatically uninstall the service and reinstall it again via my MSI package.

DetectNewerInstalledVersion: True
InstallAllUsers: True
RemovePreviousVersions: True

I upgraded the version from 1.0 to 1.1 which automatically changed the ProductCode.

In addition, if I right-click on the MSI project and choose View | Custom Actions, under each Install, Commit, Rollback and Uninstall, I have added a Custome Action from my Primary output from the actual service name.

What else do I need to do to successfully uninstall the project (I know how to do it manually via DOS commands, but is not an option)?

Answer (score 0):

Recompiled my service with the above aformentioned items (they may have existed under a different name).

I was able to successfully install | uninstall | install the service with a prompt coming up asking me if I want to "remove" the service (for the uninstall). this was successfull, then I ran the setup again to install the service.